# Rails: browser can't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, embedly

I use `embedly` card to display my content. After it call its `javascript` file, it will change link into a `embedly` card.

I have deployed into `heroku` 
https://intelligent-madame-5204.herokuapp.com/

However, after it become a embedly card, I can't use mouse to scroll down.

I put this javascript in **application.js**

```
(function(w, d){
   var id='embedly-platform', n = 'script';
   if (!d.getElementById(id)){
     w.embedly = w.embedly || function() {(w.embedly.q = w.embedly.q || []).push(arguments);};
     var e = d.createElement(n); e.id = id; e.async=1;
     e.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/platform.js';
     var s = d.getElementsByTagName(n)[0];
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
   }
  })(window, document);
```

And I put link like this way in **index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Learn More",posts.content, class: "embedly-card" %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrollbars can be turned on and off using CSS and that seems to be the issue.

Looking at the generated CSS it seems `overflow: hidden;` is being set in the body selector. If you can figure out a way to change this to `overflow: auto;` this would solve the issue. Unfortunately I have never used embedly and can't point you as to where the `body {}` might be generated from.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution.

Comment: I add `body {overflow: scroll;}` in css, and it works, Thanks! you're such a genius!

Comment: Haha not really, I'd encourage you to learn more about the quirks of CSS and creative googling and you'll be just as smart